# Python - Argparse: Default agrument that can be overridden

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing, argparse

Let's have a programme that takes a number as an input. Nonetheless, the base can be specified. When not specified, the number is in decimal base.

```sh
# 10 in decimal
./get_num.py 10

# 10 in octal
./get_num.py -o 12

# 10 in binary
./get_num.py -b 1010
```

I would like to use Python Argparse module, but cannot find a way to achieve this result. I know there is an option to use [mutually exclusive group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group) but this does not suit well, since then one need to specify base always.

Model code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from argparse import ArgumentParser


parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('base')
parser.add_argument('-o')
parser.add_argument('-b')

args = parser.parse_args()


if args.o: print('octal', args.o)
if args.b: print('binary', args.b)
else: print('decimal', args.base)
```

Comment: what if you put the base in a conditional. `if base:` and create a default template

Comment: You mean that `base` will be positional and `octal` and `binary` optional?

Comment: No base can be optional. But you can write a condition to check if base is passed. If not passed initiate the base. Post your code and I will see if I can add what you need

Comment: It's a model problem so there is not much code. But I can write it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you're after. You don't need to specify the base in the mutually exclusive group, by default required = false.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-b', action='store_true')
group.add_argument('-o', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('num', help='number')

args=parser.parse_args()

base=10  # default base
if args.b:
    base=2
elif args.o:
    base=8
# add other bases as required

print(int(args.num, base=base))
```

Output;

```
run get_num.py -b 1010
10

run get_num.py -o 12
10

run get_num.py 10
10

run get_num.py -b -o 12
usage: PROG [-h] [-b | -o] num
PROG: error: argument -o: not allowed with argument -b
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `dest`, `action='store_const'` and `const` options to `add_argument` in `argparse`, you can do this:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
parser.add_argument('value', help='Value')
group.set_defaults(base=10)
group.add_argument('-b', dest='base', action='store_const', const=2,
                   help="Use base 2")
group.add_argument('-o', dest='base', action='store_const', const=8,
                   help="Use base 8")

args = parser.parse_args()

print("Value {value}, base {base}".format(value=args.value, base=args.base))
```

with the following results:

```
$ python base.py 100
Value 100, base 10
$ python base.py 100 -b
Value 100, base 2
$ python base.py 100 -b2
usage: base.py [-h] [-b | -o] value
base.py: error: argument -b: ignored explicit argument '2'
$ python base.py 100 -o
Value 100, base 8
$ python base.py 100 -o -b
usage: base.py [-h] [-b | -o] value
base.py: error: argument -b: not allowed with argument -o
```

---

You may also consider using a `--base` option instead, with an integer value (default 10). To me, that makes your program clearer and simpler:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('value', help='Value')
parser.add_argument('-B', '--base', type=int, default=10,
                   help="Base to use")
```